# Select 1 record from first table if condition is true in second table (all refeance rows active = 0)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, phpmyadmin, inner-join

I have two tables. 
I want to select 1 record from first table if 
condition is true in second table (active = 0)

table Lead:

```
    -------------
    | id | name |
    -------------
    | 1  | abc1 |
    | 2  | abc2 |
    | 3  | abc3 |
    | 4  | abc4 |
    | 5  | abc5 |
    -------------
```

table LeadsDetails:

```
    -------------------------
    | id | lead_id | active |
    -------------------------
    | 1  | 1       | 1       |
    | 2  | 1       | 0       |
    | 3  | 2       | 0       |
    | 4  | 3       | 1       |
    | 5  | 4       | 0       |
    | 6  | 5       | 0       |
    | 7  | 5       | 0       |
    --------------------------
```

expected output:

```
    --------------
    | id | name   |
    --------------
    | 2  | abc2   |
    | 4  | abc4   |
    | 5  | abc5   |
    --------------

SELECT `Lead`.`id`, `Lead`.`name`, `Lead`.`unsubscribe` 
FROM `leads` AS `Lead` inner JOIN `LeadsDetails` AS `LeadsDetails` 
ON (`LeadsDetails`.`lead_id` = `Lead`.`id`) 
WHERE `LeadsDetails`.`active` = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should run faster than not exists because the subquery won't run for every row; in this case I'm counting the number of situations where the active field value on table leadsdetails is not 0, for the given ID, and showing only rows where that count is 0 (ie. for the given id the active field is ALWAYS 0)

```
select l.id, l.name
  from lead l
  join leadsdetails ld
    on l.id = ld.lead_id
 group by l.id, l.name
having sum(case when ld.active <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

**Fiddle:** http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00970/2/0

Answer (score 1):

As you need to get the records only when active column doesn't have 1
use `NOT EXISTS`

SQL FIDDLE DEMO : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00970/1

```
SELECT * FROM
Lead L
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM LeasdDetails LD
  where L.id = LD.lead_id
  AND LD.active =1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want with an `exists` clause:

```
select l.*
from Lead l
where exists (select 1 from LeadsDetails ld where ld.lead_id = l.id and ld.active = 0)
```