# query to get record based on joined table column array

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a query that its result is array like `$a=[1, 3, 5]`

i need another query which return records from table1 that all b values are in `$a=[1,3, 5]` so result for this sample is `table1.id=1, 2`

can i implement this with a query or i have to use php code like array_diff() to check difference between b column and $a?

```
**table1**
id   
-----------
1     ...
2     ...
3     ...

**table 2**
table1_id    b
------------
1            1
1            3
2            1
3            1
3            4  
4            1
4            3
4            5
4            4
```

Comment: Your question is not clear .. Try explain better .. show a real sampe of data an the real expected result

Comment: You can use `implode()` in PHP and an `IN()` condition im MySQL. You can also use a `JOIN`.

Comment: thank u Paul but my question was can i solve that with single sql query or i need php functions like implode() or array_diff() and .. too?

Comment: Show the two queries, that need to be combined. Ricardos answer goes in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand it correctly:

```
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table2.b IN (SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE YourCondition)
```

If you want to join multiple tables, with matching id for example, use:

```
Select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id=table2.table1_id
```

Comment: thank u  Ricardo, but condition is on table2 and  how am i suppose to compare b values per record with $a?

Comment: The YourCondition, is whatever ID from table1 you need, if you want every record from the table 1, just put "where 1"

Comment: sorry ricardo. i think i explain my question unclear. i think my answer is something like this from this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26204792/select-1-record-from-first-table-if-condition-is-true-in-second-table-all-refea            select table1.id
  from table1
  join table2
    on table1.id = table2.table1.id
 group by table1.id
having sum(case when b not in $a then 1 else 0 end) = 0